# Preventing Overlapping Ranges in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a simple way to know before saving a new document if the new document Balance From, Balance To will overlap with previously saved documents Balance From, Balance To? Thanks

[image: See image]

I followed http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLPreventRangeOverlap.aspx in sql but want to implement in mongodb.

I tried with `collection.find({fromprice:{$lt: from}, {to: {$gt: to}}})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with below solution it's working fine.

```
  if (PrinceRange.find({from: {$lte: to}, to: {$gte: from}}).count()) {
            //your error code
    }else {
            //do whatever you want to do
    }
```